# I am not able to solve the size problem in flutter splash screen

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, resize, animated-gif

The size of the GIF that I used in the splash screen is not showing in full screen.

[image: splash screen]

I want to display this GIT on the whole screen.

Please help me or suggest any way how I can display it on full screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:moms_kitchen/login_page.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SplashScreen(
        seconds: 6,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        image: new Image.asset('assets/splash1.gif'),
        loaderColor: Colors.white,
        photoSize: 250,
        navigateAfterSeconds: MainScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Mom's Kitchen",
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          fontFamily: 'LeonSans'),
      home: LoginPage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from this

```
 backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        image: new Image.asset('assets/splash1.gif'),
        loaderColor: Colors.white,
        photoSize: 250,
```

you are setting height to be 250.

to obtain device screen height you can obtain it via

```
var height=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height* 1;
```

then use height as your photosize

Comment: and for width ?

Comment: var height=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height* 1;
in this var is giving error in my program

Comment: width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,

Answer (score 0):

try something like this might help

```
child: Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `flutter_native_splash` package for a seamless splash screen on flutter apps.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your `SplashScreen` widget in a [`SafeArea`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html).

> A widget that insets its child by sufficient padding to avoid intrusions by the operating system.
>
> For example, this will indent the child by enough to avoid the status bar at the top of the screen.

Then wrap your `image` parameter in a `Container` with the device dimensions.

```dart
SafeArea(
  child: SplashScreen(
    ...
    image: Container(
      child: Image.asset('assets/splash1.gif'),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: return SafeArea(
      child: SplashScreen(
        seconds: 6,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        image: Container(
          child: Image.asset('assets/splash1.gif'),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    ),
        // loaderColor: Colors.white,
        //photoSize: 250,
        navigateAfterSeconds: MainScreen(),
      ),
    );

then also it not working error is ' the aurgument type container can not assigned to parameter type image '